# handlebars partial context

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates, handlebars.js

I have an array that contains the information for social buttons (href,alt,img). I created a partial that would cycle through the array and add the objects, here is what I have.

the array:

```
var social=[
    {

        "url":"http://twitter.com/share?text="+encodeURIComponent(this.title)+" "+encodeURIComponent('#grnsrve')+"&url="+domain+"&via="+twitterAcct,
        "image":"IMG/media/twitter_16.png",
        "alt":"twitter link"
    },
    {
        "url":"http://twitter.com/share?text="+encodeURIComponent(this.title)+" "+encodeURIComponent('#grnsrve')+"&url="+domain+"&via="+twitterAcct,
        "image":"IMG/media/twitter_16.png",
        "alt":"twitter link"
    },
    {
        "url":"http://twitter.com/share?text="+encodeURIComponent(this.title)+" "+encodeURIComponent('#grnsrve')+"&url="+domain+"&via="+twitterAcct,
        "image":"IMG/media/twitter_16.png",
        "alt":"twitter link"
    }
];
```

The template:

```
social_partial = '<a href="{{url}}" alt="{{alt}}"><img src="{{image}}"/></a>';
```

The partial function:

```
Handlebars.registerPartial('addSocial',social_partial);
```

and the main template:

```
<div class="tip_social">
    {{>addSocial social}}
</div>
```

I'm getting a 'Depth0 is undefined error'. I tried looking for documentation on parials getting a different context , but I have yet to find it.

**edit** [here](http://jsfiddle.net/EjywE/) is a more complete fiddle of it

Answer (score 8):

Same issue for me. Bit of digging and one face-palm later here's what I've found.

### tl;dr answer

Be **very** careful about the context you pass to your partial. If you somehow pass a null, or empty object to your partial you'll get the `depth0 is undefined` error

### Very slightly longer answer

#### JSFiddle Examples:

- depth0 bug gets triggered http://jsfiddle.net/paulcollinsiii/dAmfc/
- working version http://jsfiddle.net/paulcollinsiii/sMAkT/

The only thing that changed in the working version is I'm passing a valid context to the partial.

BTW a very helpful trick is to use the debug helper from [this blog](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/handlebars-js-part-3-tips-and-tricks)

#### Answerbot dictator "code example"

```
<script id="parent">
 <table>
   <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>One</th>
        <th>Two</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {{#each collection}}
       {{>myPartial nothingHere}} <!-- Broken context -->
    {{/each}}
    </tbody>
 </table>
</script>
```

The broken context above will cause handlebars to die. For your problem try digging into that with a `{{debug}}` tag and see if that helps.

For a better code example please just take a look at the jsFiddles. Reposting all the code in here, formatting it to make it pretty looking and making the StackOverflow answerbot dictator happy was a bit much for doing this at work ^_~

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you're doing wrong as you haven't provided enough code to duplicate your problem. However, it isn't hard to make it work. First of all, your main template should be iterating over `social` and feeding each element to your partial, something like this:

```
<script id="t" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    {{#each social}}
        <div class="tip_social">
            {{>addSocial this}}
        </div>
    {{/each}}
</script>
```

And then you can get your HTML with something like this:

```
​var t    = Handlebars.compile($('#t').html());
var html = t({social: social}));​​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/SsdbU/1/

Comment: How would this integrate with the main template though? I'm not sure what the 2nd line of JS means

Comment: @alme1304: Your main template doesn't make a lot of sense unless you're looping over `social` in JavaScript. When you compile a Handlebars template, you get a function back, then you execute that function to get your HTML.

Comment: Not sure what you mean in the first sentence. How would I access those javascript variables within the template? would a helper function be the answer instead?

Comment: @alme1304: Maybe if you provide a functional example I can help you.

Comment: That doesn't even get to the partial, you have missing variables and a `$.ajax` call that won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the only way I found:
Handlebars doc indicates that you need to use Block Helpers to pass different contexts. So here are two files: the main template and the script in node contening two contexts: the main context and the context for the social data. The script having the source for the partial template. The Block is #twitter_list and its associated registerHelper uses option.fn(other_context_object) which seems the only way to pass another context in handlebars.

Main template:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test content</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
    <div id = main>
        <!-- This is using the main context-->
        <h2> Hello {{name}}!</h2>
        <p>{{some_content}}</p>


        <!-- This is using the partial template and its own context -->
        <ul>
        {{#twitter_list}}
            {{>yourpartial}}
        {{/twitter_list}}
        </ul>

    </div>  

</body>
</html>
```

The javascript using Node js:

```
var handlebars = require('handlebars'),
fs = require('fs');

const main_context = { name: "world",
                        some_content: "Bla bla bla all my bla bla"};

const twitter_data={social:[
    {
        "url":"some url 1",
        "image":"IMG/media/twitter_1.png",
        "alt":"twitter link 1"
    },
    {
        "url":"some url 2",
        "image":"IMG/media/twitter_2.png",
        "alt":"twitter link 2"
    },
    {
        "url":"some url 3",
        "image":"IMG/media/twitter_3.png",
        "alt":"twitter link 3"
    }
]};


var partial_source = '{{#each social}}<li><a href="{{url}}" alt="{{alt}}"><img src="{{image}}"/></a></li>{{/each}}';

handlebars.registerPartial('yourpartial', partial_source);

handlebars.registerHelper('twitter_list', function(options) {
    //you need to use the options.fn to pass the specific context
    return options.fn(twitter_data);
});

fs.readFile('maintemplate1.hbs', 'utf-8', function(error, source){
  var template = handlebars.compile(source);
  var html = template(main_context);
  console.log(html)
});
```